# How to integrate Django Rest Framework Api with a front in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular

This is my first contact with AngularJS. I would like to integrate the api with a front in Angular, my goal is just to return a list of data, making it as simple as possible is my goal. [image: API screen]

Comment: What have you accomplished so far?

Comment: so far I've found that the easiest way is to use the angular httpclient library.@jo-chris

Comment: i recommend you come up with some ideas from yourself and then get back here. Create an endpoint in your django rest api, and try to call that endpoint with the httpclient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[link[][1]](https://angular.io/guide/http)    Setup for server communication
Before you can use HttpClient, you need to import the Angular HttpClientModule. Most apps do so in the root AppModule.

```
app/app.module.ts (excerpt)


    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

You can then inject the HttpClient service as a dependency of an application class, as shown in the following ConfigService example.

app/config/config.service.ts (excerpt)

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class ConfigService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    }
    The HttpClient service makes use of observables for all transactions. You must import the RxJS observable and operator symbols that appear in the example snippets. These ConfigService imports are typical.

app/config/config.service.ts (RxJS imports)
content_copy
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
```